# Creating Array from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to create array like this:

```
$data = array("15:05" => 1745, "15:10" => 1751,....);
```

My database looks like this:

```
id | cloak | prize
1  | 15:05 | 1745
2  | 15:10 | 1751
```

This is my code, but it doesnt work.

```
<?php
include('config.php');


$record=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM btc_archive");
$list = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){


    $list[] = array($row['price']=>$row['cloak']);
}

var_dump($list);


?>
```

How I can make it work?

Comment: do $list[$row['cloak']] = $row['prize']; then read up on coding basics.

Comment: You mean: `$list[] = ["${row[cloak]}" => $row['price']];` ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
$record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM btc_archive");
$list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
    $list[$row['cloak']] = $row['price'];
}

var_dump($list);
```

This is what you want.

Comment: But it still gives me a little bit different result.

I would like to have this array in this form:
$data = array("1" => .0032, "2" => .0028, "3" => .0021, "4" => .0033, 
"5" => .0034, "6" => .0031, "7" => .0036, "8" => .0027, "9" => .0024, 
"10" => .0021, "11" => .0026, "12" => .0024, "13" => .0036, 
"14" => .0028, "15" => .0025);

and I get:

array(3) { [1570]=> string(8) "15:58:16" [1571]=> string(8) "15:11:49" [1593]=> string(8) "16:00:01" }

Comment: You posted something else in your question.